# How to combine characters of value in xarray dataset

Tags: python, arrays, netcdf, python-xarray

I am extremely new to coding, so please correct me on anything I'm misunderstanding.

I need to find a way to combine the different characters in each value into a single string of characters. The data originally came from a netcdf file that I opened in xarray. The dtype was originally |S1, but I was able to convert it to a string using .astype(str) and then transposing, and this was the result.

```
ncases_OFCL: 2743, nchars_basin: 2

array([['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ...,
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p']], dtype='<U1')

Coordinates: (0)
Attributes:

long_name :
    OFCL basin
units :
```

Now that I've gotten to this point, is there a way to join the 'a' and 'l' and so on into just 'al'? Thank you for any help you can give!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you.

```
data  = np.array([['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p']])

data2 = []
for n in range(0,len(data)):
    data2.append(data[n,0] + data[n,1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I tried this, I got an error: "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> None". I'm not exactly sure how to manage this. Any advice?

Comment: The error likely has to do with the data structure you are using. Can you tell me more about the data structure or source code that you're working with? I'm using a numpy array and a list, if you can convert the xarray structure to a numpy array or a list, my solution should work

Comment: Sure, I'll try to explain as best as I can. The data came in a netcdf file which I opened using xarray. The dimensions are leadtimes_OFCL: 41, ncases_OFCL: 2743, nchars_basin: 2, nchars_time: 10. The variables are 
vmax_OFCL
(leadtimes_OFCL, ncases_OFCL)
float64

basin_OFCL
(nchars_basin, ncases_OFCL)
|S1

stnum_OFCL
(ncases_OFCL)
float64

time_OFCL
(nchars_time, ncases_OFCL)
|S1

I need to work with both basin_OFCL and time_OFCL in this same way, as they have the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data is encoded as a fixed-width unicode array type, and you can't resize fixed-width character arrays.

Your data probably looks something like this:

```py
In [16]: da = xr.DataArray(
    ...:     np.array([['a', 'l']] * 10 + [['e', 'p']] * 10).astype('U'),
    ...:     dims=['ncases_OFCL', 'nchars_basin'],
    ...: )

In [17]: da
Out[17]:
<xarray.DataArray (ncases_OFCL: 20, nchars_basin: 2)>
array([['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['a', 'l'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p'],
       ['e', 'p']], dtype='<U1')
Dimensions without coordinates: ncases_OFCL, nchars_basin
```

You can sum the characters along a dimension if you first convert the data to object type:

```py
In [18]: da.astype('O').sum(dim='nchars_basin')
Out[18]:
<xarray.DataArray (ncases_OFCL: 20)>
array(['al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'ep',
       'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep'], dtype=object)
Dimensions without coordinates: ncases_OFCL
```

If you'd like, you could convert back to fixed-width `'<U2'` type:

```py
In [19]: da.astype('O').sum(dim='nchars_basin').astype('U')
Out[19]:
<xarray.DataArray (ncases_OFCL: 20)>
array(['al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'al', 'ep',
       'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep', 'ep'], dtype='<U2')
Dimensions without coordinates: ncases_OFCL
```